# PANDAS Substitute non null column values with key value pairs of a dict

Tags: pandas, dictionary, dataframe, match

Suppose I have a dataframe:
df1:

```
       AC BC AK BJ  SDFG.... (1100 such columns)
Tom    0  0  1   0   0
Sally  1  0  1   1   0
Nick   0  1  0   0   1
```

I also have a dict where :

```
dict_1= {'AC':0.23,'BC':1.2, 'AK':0.45, 'BJ': 2.2, 'ABFK':4.5....}
```

it's not necessary that all keys in dict1 are columns of df1, the total number of key value pairs may be 10,000, and columns are only 1100. SO significant number of keys are not columns like for 'ABFK' key is not there in df1
Similarly there might be column names which are not keys in dict_1. For e.g 'SDFG' column header has no associated key in dict.

I would like to return a dataframe where in dict1 the value has been substituted if the key exists as a column name:
for e.g what I would like to get back is

```
      AC    BC   AK    BJ    SDFG.... (1100 such columns) TOTAL
Tom    0    0    0.45   0     0                             0.45
Sally  0.23 0    0.45   2.2   0                             2.7
Nick   0    1.2  0      0     0.13                          1.33
```

So all(1s) have been substituted by values based on dictionary . If the key didn't exist like SDFG  it is changed to a default value of 0.13. In the end I would like to have a total column name which sums across the row.

What would be an easy PANDAS solution for this?
Thanks a lot to all those who would help a novice out.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**
You can use `mask` to hide ones, then use `assign` with dictionary unpacking to fill in those masked values.

First, create a new dictionary where we fill in the defaults

```
d = {c: dict_1.get(c, .13) for c in df}
df.mask(df == 1, df.assign(**d))

         AC   BC    AK   BJ  SDFG
Tom    0.00  0.0  0.45  0.0  0.00
Sally  0.23  0.0  0.45  2.2  0.00
Nick   0.00  1.2  0.00  0.0  0.13
```

---

To include the `Total` column

```
d = {c: dict_1.get(c, .13) for c in df}
d1 = df.mask(df == 1, df.assign(**d))
d1 = d1.assign(Total=d1.sum(1))
d1

         AC   BC    AK   BJ  SDFG  Total
Tom    0.00  0.0  0.45  0.0  0.00   0.45
Sally  0.23  0.0  0.45  2.2  0.00   2.88
Nick   0.00  1.2  0.00  0.0  0.13   1.33
```

---

**Option 2**
Or, we could have used `replace` where we pass a dictionary that defines what to replace for that particular column.

```
df.replace({c: {1: dict_1.get(c, .13)} for c in df})

         AC   BC    AK   BJ  SDFG
Tom    0.00  0.0  0.45  0.0  0.00
Sally  0.23  0.0  0.45  2.2  0.00
Nick   0.00  1.2  0.00  0.0  0.13
```

We can proceed to add a `Total` column in the same manner as above.

---

**Option 3**
We could create a new `pd.Series` and `reindex` with `df.columns` then `fillna` with `.13`

```
# thanks @jezrael for fill_value reminder
df * pd.Series(dict_1).reindex(df.columns, fill_value=.13)

         AC   BC    AK   BJ  SDFG
Tom    0.00  0.0  0.45  0.0  0.00
Sally  0.23  0.0  0.45  2.2  0.00
Nick   0.00  1.2  0.00  0.0  0.13
```

We can proceed to add a `Total` column in the same manner as above

Comment: This was an great solution.Thanks!

Comment: @Pearl glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can first update `dict` and then use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) for `NaN`s which are replaced by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
dict_1= {'AC':0.23,'BC':1.2, 'AK':0.45, 'BJ': 2.2, 'ABFK':4.5}

dict_2 = {x: 0.13 for x in df.columns if x not in dict_1}
dict_2.update(dict_1)

df = df.mask(df == 1).fillna(df.columns.to_series().replace(dict_2))
df['TOTAL'] = df.sum(axis=1)
print (df)
         AC   BC    AK   BJ  SDFG  TOTAL
Tom    0.00  0.0  0.45  0.0  0.00   0.45
Sally  0.23  0.0  0.45  2.2  0.00   2.88
Nick   0.00  1.2  0.00  0.0  0.13   1.33
```